# change starting index when assigning one array to another in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am using str_split() to split a long strings into an array of length 16 each. And I'm assigning the returned array to one in my function. Like this:

```
$myarray = str_split($string, 16);
```

The problem is that I want the indexing of $myarray to start from a number other than 0, say 50. Currently I'm doing this:

```
foreach($myarray as $id => $value)
{    
    $myarray[$id + 50] = $value;
    unset($myarray[$id]);
}
```

Is there a better solution? Because the arrays and strings I'm dealing with are very long. Thanks

Comment: What's your reasoning for doing this? There's likely a better way to handle the underlying situation ...

Comment: I'm reading the string from disk. It contains binary data with each 16 characters making up sort of a node. Splitting the string gives me an array of nodes. The indices of these nodes need to be consistent for subsequent disk reads as all of the data cannot be retrieved in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_pad()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php).

```
$myarray = str_split($string, 16);
$myarray = array_pad($myarray, -(size($myarray)+50), null);
```

It will fill the first 50 elements with nulls and push the rest of the array forward by 50 elements.

Comment: Okay, but that way, I will be wasting like 87000*16 bytes of memory a lot of times :D

Comment: why? All it would do is pad the array is 50 nulls in front of it. If the array is 500 elements large, padding it with -550 will make 50 elements at the beginning of the array, please take a look at the link I gave in the first line of the answer.

Comment: Oh.. I forgot that putting null means unsetting the variable. I am a C programmer :P You are right. Thanks :)